# RegExp & PCRE convert to tree with own syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, pcre, preprocessor

Looking for pre-processor for creating own syntax of regular expression, based on RegExp & PCRE syntax so it can be parsed to PCRE syntax. Example at the end

I guess I need a processor of regular expression that outputs a tree structure that represents regular expression, so I can traverse the tree and hotswap some parts, then compile it to regular expression string.

But this processor must have ability to add own syntax parsing/processing.

Is there some processor like this, already made by someone? I've made one by myself some time ago, but looking for more professional solution.

Of course we are talking about node.js/javascript

Yes, node.js has not support for PCRE, but there is a npm module for using PCRE with node.js, it works great!

---

Why someone would need it?

For example, you can create big regular expression by smaller ones:

```
(John (like|love)s every (animal|creature) on earth: (#animals))
```

(#...) is hash tag group, it means in place of it will be another regular expression containing alterantives for all animals.

Another example, you can create more sophisticated kind of groups:

```
(@(a|x)(b)(c))
```

permutation group matches all brackets (3 or less or more) in any order:

```
(a|x)(b)(c)
(a|x)(c)(b)
(b)(a|x)(c)
(b)(c)(a|x)
(c)(a|x)(b)
(c)(b)(a|x)
```

have more, but I guess I've made a point.

Comment: Please read post before clicking "close" it is so rude when you click it without reason! Be nice!

Comment: One such library would be [xregexp](http://xregexp.com) which provides utilities for syntax extensions ("addons").